# CSS - Adding a right aligned button on top of dynamic size div with scroll bars

Tags: css

This is our code. css:

```
   .mydiv 
    {

        position: absolute;
        background-color: white; 
        margin-top:40px;
        display: block;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, 0);
        max-width:10%;
        max-height:30%;
        overflow: auto;
     }
```

body

```
 <div class="mydiv">
    <img border="0" src="http://atldunia.com/youtube/FixedP7.jpg" /> 
</div>
```

This div automatically adjusts to the size of the contents. Both the scroll bars appear on demand. However, we are unable to add a button that is right aligned and appears outside the scroll making it always visible.

http://atldunia.com/youtube/FixedPosPopup7.htm

Comment: This question is poorly stated and the code poorly written (inline style and empty paragraph tags?) unless there is more code that you are not sharing? Either way it sounds like you need to read up on absolute positioning http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: Thanks. Code reformatted. We have browsed that site and many other similar sites. This is far more challenging.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wish to add a "close" button.  If so, you can wrap your content in another layer and add the button to the first.

```css
.popup-wrapper { display:block; position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; transform:translate(-50%, -50%); max-width:400px; max-height:400px; overflow:hidden; }

.popup-close { display:block; position:absolute; right:0; top:0; width:32px; height:32px;
 background:#404040; line-height:32px; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; font-size:24px;
 color:#909090; cursor:default; }

.popup-close:hover { background:#808080; color:#c0c0c0; }

.popup-content { display:block; position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:auto; }

.popup-content > img { display:block; position:relative; width:auto; height:auto; }
```

```html
<div class="popup-wrapper">
  <div class="popup-content"><img src="http://atldunia.com/youtube/FixedP7.jpg"/></div>
  <span class="popup-close">&times;</span>
</div>
```

You will need modify a couple things to your liking, but you get the idea.

Comment: DRAB.  This div expands and shrinks based on if contents exceed max-width / max-height in %  therefore NO to any Pixels.

Comment: @Shankar Yea, no problem, just modify the max-width and max-height to your liking (% if that's what you want).  I used pixels so viewing/testing the snippet works a bit better.

Comment: DRAB. That wont work. Position absolute or fixed is the ONLY  way to create both V & H scroll bars around a dynamic div. Any wrapper around an absolute or fixed div is thrown out of the flow. Try and see it for yourself. This needs some tricky workaround than the usual answers. Good luck.

Comment: @Shankar Indeed, it would seem that the size calculations of the inner content does not regard its parent's "max-height" or "max-width" properties.  In this case, I would suggest setting a pixel limit (as shown in the snippet), or, if you're intent on sizing the content of the pop-up proportionately to the browser window, then perhaps a "light-box" method could do you well.  That way, again presuming that your original question is related to adding a "close" button, the pop-up may be closed by clicking on the whitespace surrounding the pop-up.

Comment: I have no issues with the div or the contents. if I set the max-width to 80% the div WONT  expand  unless the content try to exceed 80%  of the browser size ; in that case the scroll bar would appear. I love this div ; it is very fluid. Issue is that I am unable to wrap anything around this div.